# Odd perfect numbers

Tags: math-history, perfect-numbers

In [this other question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4690948), somebody mentions that in a letter to Mersenne dated November 15, 1638, Descartes showed that $D=3^2⋅7^2⋅11^2⋅13^2⋅22021=198585576189$ would be an odd perfect number if $22021$ were prime.

As far as I can see, the sum of the divisors of $D$ equals:

$$ S(D) = (1+3+3^2) \cdot (1+7+7^2) \cdot (1+11+11^2) \cdot (1+13+13^2) + (1+22021)$$

Doing some calculation, this becomes:

$$S(D) = 13 \cdot 57 \cdot 133 \cdot 183 \cdot 22022$$

That second factor has $19$ as a prime factor ($57=3 \cdot 19$ and even $133=7 \cdot 19$), but $D$ does not have $19$ as a prime factor. As far as I can judge, when a number is perfect, then the sum of its divisors is the double of that number, so it can't have any other new prime factors (except for $2$, obviously).

So, even if $22021$ were a prime number, $D$ would still not be a perfect number.

Am I making a mistake here?

Comment: ??? Are you saying that Descartes **used** the prime factors of that number and at the same number supposed that number to be **prime**? (He didn't have a good day, I imagine) :-)

Comment: As @Sil says - if you multiply out you get the equality you need - which would be a round-about way of finding the prime factors of 22021.

Comment: @Dominique Your argumentation is true , if $n$ and $\sigma(n)$ are actually factored into primes. If $22021$ WERE prime , it would have to occur in the sum of the divisors as well. This is not the case. The number would be a perfect number in the sense that the usual formula for the divisor sum would give $\sigma(n)=2n$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no mistake (apart from assuming that $22021$ is a prime, of course), the primes $19$ and $61$ will not be in this "prime factorization" because $19^2\cdot 61=22021$ and we pretend $22021$ is already a prime, so no new prime numbers except $2$ are introduced as expected. In short $S(D)=2\cdot 3^2 \cdot 7^2 \cdot 11^2  \cdot 13^2 \cdot 22021=2D$. Of course you could just calculate both $S(D)$ and $2D$ as you did, multiply everything out and compare they are in fact equal.

For more info see also https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Descartes_number, it has the full factorization written out.

Answer (score 2):

$1+13+13^2\ne 182$. It should be $183$.

Comment: Indeed. This contains prime factor $61$, which makes it even worse.

Comment: @Dominique:  Actually, that prime factor $61$ is there for a very special reason.  ^_^

Answer (score 0):

@Dominique: I invite you to read [Odd, spoof perfect factorizations](https://arxiv.org/abs/2006.10697) by the BYU Computational Number Theory Group, led by Pace Nielsen, who is also one of the number theory experts who work on odd perfect numbers.

Here is a portion of the abstract:

> > "We show that the structure of odd, spoof perfect factorizations is extremely rich, and there are multiple infinite families of them. **This implies that certain approaches to the odd perfect number problem that use only the multiplicative nature of the sum-of-divisors function are unworkable.** On the other hand, we prove that there are only finitely many nontrivial, odd, primitive spoof perfect factorizations with a fixed number of bases."